# Code resuse in an unified ASp.NET MVC and WebAPI application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, web, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a web application using ASP.NET MVC that needs to be accessible via a web browser (via Views), as well as from mobile applications via Web API. The thing is that I would like to avoid duplicating business logic in controllers for Views (inherited from Controller) and controllers for Web API (inherited from ApiController).

Basically I would like to go with a design where the web application is simply using the Web API, and all the business logic is implemented in the Web API.

View <-> Controller <-> Web API Controller <-> Data Model

What is the best way to design such an application? Is there a simple way to call Web API controllers from the same MVC application? Or is it better to go with two separate applications/projects?

Comment: Put all of the business logic in a class library and reference it from both MVC and Web API controllers. You could make HTTP requests from your MVC app to your API controllers but that seems unnecessary unless you have an infrastructure-related reason for it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also worried that the Web API capabilities will be behind the app functionality (as it often happens with APIs). To avoid this I plan to require to expose all the application's functionality through the Web API by making it a necessary layer.

Comment: That's fair enough, then I'd use something like RestSharp to make HTTP requests to your API controllers. Don't try and call them directly like so many people seem so insistent on doing.

Comment: Are there significant performance implication of doing HTTP requests instead of calling the api controllers directly?  What's bad in calling them directly (and I don't know how to do it anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is an approach that looks like your problem. And other advices are [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/01/on-the-coexistence-of-asp-net-mvc-and-webapi.aspx).

Comment: Not exactly. This approach would require to expose every function in three places (MVC UI, Web API and the Application). #3 from your link would fit much better because it's only three places (MVC UI and WebAPI), but I don't like an idea to use HTTP inside the app where it seems unnecessary overhead.